# What is a SQL Server "GDR"?

Tags: sql-server, linux, update, terminology

Microsoft provides hosts two repos,

- https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/mssql-server-2017-gdr-xenial/
- https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/mssql-server-2017-xenial/

What does GDR stand for in that context.

You can find it on [Microsoft sites but they don't explain it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3210089/gdr-update-package-for-sql-server-2016-sp1)

> GDR update package for SQL Server 2016 SP1

You can see it [here too](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803383.aspx).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A General Distribution Release (GDR) is simply a kind of hotfix, or patch that contains specific fixes, and is intended for installation on all SQL instances.  This is in contrast to a Quick Fix Engineering (QFE) hotfix, which is intended to be installed only if you experience a particular issue.

After a hotfix, it will also be included in the next Cumulative Update (CU) or Service Pack (SP).  But you can install the hotfix without taking all the changes included in the next CU/SP.

Going forward GDR hotfixes are only going to contain security fixes.

For SQL Server 2017+ a GDR is part of the Modern Servicing Model (MSM), which is replacing the older Incremental Servicing Model (ISM), which will continue to apply to SQL Server 2016 and before.  It's [explained here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/announcing-the-modern-servicing-model-for-sql-server/).

Comment: Amazing how complicated it may be, just as terminology, not to mention usability...